# application is getting flashed while calling web services in iOS

Tags: objective-c, web-services

i am using Soap web services to download the data from server. Device is getting flashed like flash light while downloading data. i am using synchrous request to get the data.
I could nt find out the reason why its getting flashed.
Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
NSString *msgString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                               "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " 
                               "xmlns:xsd=\"http://http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " 
                               "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                               "<soap:Body>"
                               "<GetCategories xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"/>"
                               "</soap:Body>"
                               "</soap:Envelope>"]; 
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[DefaultSettings getLink]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
        //---set the various headers---
        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [msgString length]];
        [req addValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetCategories" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
        [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        //---set the HTTP method and body---
        [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [req setHTTPBody:[msgString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
 NSData *webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
                [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
                [xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
                [xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
                [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
                [xmlParser parse];
```

after this, i am parsing the data. In the same method, i am calling 8 soap services one by one.

Comment: please post some code! otherwise it is almost impossible to determine the problem.

Comment: Please see the code, I have sent code

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using
 `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];`. 
This method fires a synchronous connection and block the thread until you get a response from the server.

You can use wether 
`- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately` 
to start an asynchronous connection or start your previous method from another thread using NSThread

If your app is doing more than one request, you should create a RequestManager that will perform all the requests. This Manager will implements the `NSURLConnectionDelegate`. Then create your own protocol and implement it in your ViewController subclasses.

for instance, in your protocol you can add a method called

```
- (void)request:(int)requestID didFinishWithResult:(NSData *)data
```

the requestID is used to identify your request.

Call this method when any request finishes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But here i need to implement NSURLConnection  delegate methods for many classes. calling service asynchronous  is not getting delegate methods called from modal class.